# RXjava deserilization

Tags: java, spring, rx-java

I get a runtime exception when my http(204) is empty when doing a blockingget.
It doesnt seem to be able to deserialize a null/empty http response.
Is there a way to do this without getting an exception?
Since I'm using spring it marks my transaction as rolledback I want to avoid that because getting an empty body is not an error.

```
Single<myobject> cp = cpApi.findOne(myparam);
try {
    return cp.blockingGet();
} catch(RuntimeException t) {
    throw new RuntimeException(t.getMessage());
}
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   com.myproject.model.myobject  at
>   io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:59)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle$SingleElementObserver.onComplete(ObservableSingleSingle.java:111)
>     at
>   retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onComplete(BodyObservable.java:66)
>     at
>   retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:48)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Not the most elegant solution but it works.

```
myobject notfound = new myobject();
Single<myobject> cp = cpApi.findOne(myparam);
myobject r = cp.onErrorReturnItem(notfound).blockingGet();
if(r.equals(notfound))
   return null;
return r;
```